# My navigation bar is vertical but won't go horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've been having trouble making my navigation bar for some reason. I've tried looking at if anything here answers it or going online but have had no luck. Am I missing something or is there a conflict?

```css
 
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .container {
      max-width: 940px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
    
    
    .jumbotron {
      background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 800px;
    }
    
    .header {
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .nav {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
    
    .nav li a {
      color: #fff;
      display: inline;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav" role="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reading</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made you a plunker as an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UdFkRz1gA5APAyPqARnj?p=preview). You were very close. You just need to set the `display` property on the `.nav li` selector to `inline-block`.

```
.nav li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The poster was actually looking for a Bootstrap solution but didn't have the question tagged as such. Here is a Bootstrap [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uS3b0Jqo1VgLAFDzdPL5?p=preview). It just uses the `pull-left` class on each `li` tag.

```
<ul class="nav" role="navigation">
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Reading</a></li>
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was using bootstrap and it works when I do that, but I had to delete the CDN link to disable bootstrap. You have any idea why it doesn't work with it?

Comment: To get the same result using bootstrap add the `pull-left` class to each of the `li` tags in your menu. I made an updated example using the bootstrap method here: https://plnkr.co/edit/uS3b0Jqo1VgLAFDzdPL5?p=preview In the future remember to tag bootstrap if you're looking for a bootstrap answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, try adding

```
.nav li {
 display: inline;
}
```

Your li elements are naturally block displayed, so this should go ahead and remove the breaks from in between them.

Answer (score 0):

See the fixed code snippet bellow. You need to add `display: inline;` to the `li` elements to make them go horizontal.

```css
    li {
      display: inline;
    }

    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .container {
      max-width: 940px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
    
    
    .jumbotron {
      background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 800px;
    }
    
    .header {
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .nav {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
    
    .nav li a {
      color: #fff;
      display: inline;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav" role="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reading</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `.nav li` with inline display.

```
.nav li{
   display: inline;
}
```